# kafkajs - Wrong password for SASL authentication did not raise an error

Tags: security, authentication, apache-kafka, passwords, kafkajs

This is my producer using [`kafkajs`](https://kafka.js.org/). When I provide incorrect user name in `options.username`, I see the message `Connected`. How do I handle connection errors with `kafkajs`?

```js
const { Kafka, logLevel } = require('kafkajs')

async function kafkaProducer(options) {
    const kafka = new Kafka({
        brokers: [options.bootstrapServer],
        clientId: options.clientId,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            ca: [fs.readFileSync(options.caCertPath, 'utf-8')]
        },
        sasl: {
            mechanism: options.saslMechanism, // PLAIN
            username: options.username,
            password: options.password
        },
        requestTimeout: 2000,
        retry: {
            retries: 1
        },
        logLevel: logLevel.ERROR
    })
    //
    const producer = kafka.producer()
    try {
        await producer.connect()
        console.log('Connected')
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant `server.properties`. How did you set up SASL on broker side?

Answer (score 1):

KafkaJS will throw an error on `connect` if authentication fails. [See this test for example](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/cfbb49d2133719683babe07c9e3d33068a3dae4a/src/producer/index.spec.js#L121-L135).

It is very likely that you haven't set up authentication on the broker side correctly. [See the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/sasl.html#sasl-configuration-for-kafka-brokers) for information on how to configure SASL on the broker.